# Get the item that appears the most times in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, search

```
var store = ['1','2','2','3','4'];
```

I want to find out that `2` appear the most in the array. How do I go about doing that?

Comment: is that array always sorted (as it is in your example)?

Comment: See here for my pseudo-code answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3774757/c-get-mode-from-list-of-integers/3774791#3774791

Comment: If the answer to @Thilo's question is yes, same elements will always be grouped together. This allows you to loop through the list once comparing each item to the previous one and keeping a count of how many same elements you've encountered and the highest run encountered along the way. At the end of the loop, you'll have your answer. This will run in linear time. If the answer to @Thilo's question is no, then sort the list first, followed by the strategy above.

Comment: @Asaph: if the array is not sorted, codaddict's algorithm is better than sorting (if you can spare the extra memory for the frequency counters)

Comment: @Thilo: True. It's a little better. But sorting is not such a big expense. @codaddict's algorithm runs in linear space and linear time. My suggestion runs in constant space and O(n log n + n) time, depending on sorting algorithm.

Comment: @Thilo nope it isn't but i guess i can make it sort in this manner according @Asaph

Comment: If the `2` appears more than `N/2` times, this can solved in `O(n)` using `Boyer-Moore Majority Voting Algorithm`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get the element with the highest occurrence in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053843/get-the-element-with-the-highest-occurrence-in-an-array)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I would do something like:

```
var store = ['1','2','2','3','4'];
var frequency = {};  // array of frequency.
var max = 0;  // holds the max frequency.
var result;   // holds the max frequency element.
for(var v in store) {
        frequency[store[v]]=(frequency[store[v]] || 0)+1; // increment frequency.
        if(frequency[store[v]] > max) { // is this frequency > max so far ?
                max = frequency[store[v]];  // update max.
                result = store[v];          // update result.
        }
}
```

Comment: +1 - Very nice... But I would use a `for` loop to block corner cases where the array object has properties: http://jsfiddle.net/9eJd3/

Comment: I'd suggest the addition of `if (store.hasOwnProperty(v))` in case someone has decided to modify Object or Array's prototype, as folks seem to be somewhat keen on that doing around here ;P

Comment: @no - That's not good enough, since `store` can have its own properties that **are not** values of the array. ( http://jsfiddle.net/vR5JK/ ). A `for` loop will do the trick though, since anything outside the values in the array are not included in `store[0]` to `store[store.length]`

Comment: Ooops, by `for` loop I meant `for(var v=0; v < store.length; ++v){...}`.

Comment: @Peter Ajtai - I saw your example, but that would actually be the behavior I'd expect... I'd want every property of the array object counted, regardless of whether the property also represents an array index. That way it can work for regular objects too. I guess it depends on what behavior you want.

Comment: On the other hand I'd definitely *not* want cute function properties that someone added to Array.prototype or Object.prototype to show up. Just sayin.

Comment: @no - Methods can be added directly to an array and not to Array.prototype: http://jsfiddle.net/YHFqJ/ ---- But yeah, it just depends on your view  of what an "Array" is... Guess I'm not as open mined as you ;)

Comment: @Peter Ajtai: sure, but I'm hoping nobody would ever _do_ that... and if they are, maybe they're adding the same function more than once and they want to see which one occurs the mosst times ;p

Answer (score 7):

Solution with emphasis to `Array.prototype.forEach` and the problem of getting more than one key if the max count is shared among more items.

Edit: Proposal with one loop, only.

```js
var store = ['1', '2', '2', '3', '4', '5', '5'],
    distribution = {},
    max = 0,
    result = [];

store.forEach(function (a) {
    distribution[a] = (distribution[a] || 0) + 1;
    if (distribution[a] > max) {
        max = distribution[a];
        result = [a];
        return;
    }
    if (distribution[a] === max) {
        result.push(a);
    }
});
console.log('max: ' + max);
console.log('key/s with max count: ' + JSON.stringify(result));
console.log(distribution);
```

Answer (score 5):

```
arr.sort();
    var max=0,result,freq = 0;
    for(var i=0; i < arr.length; i++){
        if(arr[i]===arr[i+1]){
            freq++;
        }
        else {
            freq=0;
        }
        if(freq>max){
            result = arr[i];
            max = freq;
        }
    }
    return result;
```

Comment: As there are many other answers, it might be helpful to add an explanation as to why your solution is preferable. You can add an explanation by clicking the "edit" button...

Comment: Does arr.sort() always sort group of different types in array correctly?

Comment: yes @ user2734550. arr.sort() is able to sort group of different types in array correctly. but if you are dealing with single together with muliple digit numbers, you may need to sort this way: arr.sort(function(a,b){return a- b;})

Comment: Thank you. I really like your solution! simple to read and easy to understand. Works for strings too.

Comment: I like your solution because it uses more basic JavaScript instructions that are common to most C-family languages.

Answer (score 2):

Make a histogram, find the key for the maximum number in the histogram.

```
var hist = [];
for (var i = 0; i < store.length; i++) {
  var n = store[i];
  if (hist[n] === undefined) hist[n] = 0;
  else hist[n]++;
}

var best_count = hist[store[0]];
var best = store[0];
for (var i = 0; i < store.length; i++) {
  if (hist[store[i]] > best_count) {
    best_count = hist[store[i]];
    best = store[i];
  }
}

alert(best + ' occurs the most at ' + best_count + ' occurrences');
```

This assumes either there are no ties, or you don't care which is selected.

Comment: Not necessary if the array is sorted, though. Then it can be a single-pass operation.

Comment: As a side note, this is called the mode of the distribution.

Answer (score 2):

Another ES6 option. Works with strings or numbers.

```
function mode(arr) {
  const store = {}
  arr.forEach((num) => store[num] ? store[num] += 1 : store[num] = 1)
  return Object.keys(store).sort((a, b) => store[b] - store[a])[0]
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

If the array is sorted this should work:

```
function popular(array) { 
   if (array.length == 0) return [null, 0];
   var n = max = 1, maxNum = array[0], pv, cv;

   for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++, pv = array[i-1], cv = array[i]) {
      if (pv == cv) { 
        if (++n >= max) {
           max = n; maxNum = cv;
        }
      } else n = 1;
   }

   return [maxNum, max];
};

popular([1,2,2,3,4,9,9,9,9,1,1])
[9, 4]

popular([1,2,2,3,4,9,9,9,9,1,1,10,10,10,10,10])
[10, 5]
```

Comment: The values don't need to be ordered, just grouped. Fewer comparisons arise if the current _mode candidate_'s frequency is checked `if (pv != cv)`.

Comment: @greybeard, does arr.sort() do 'grouping' well? I know it doesn't sort so well for different types, but does it do grouping correctly?

Answer (score 0):

This version will quit looking when the count exceeds the number of items not yet counted.

It works without sorting the array.

```
Array.prototype.most= function(){
    var L= this.length, freq= [], unique= [], 
    tem, max= 1, index, count;
    while(L>= max){
        tem= this[--L];
        if(unique.indexOf(tem)== -1){
            unique.push(tem);
            index= -1, count= 0;
            while((index= this.indexOf(tem, index+1))!= -1){
                ++count;
            }
            if(count> max){
                freq= [tem];
                max= count;
            }
            else if(count== max) freq.push(tem);
        }
    }
    return [freq, max];
}

    //test
    var A= ["apples","oranges","oranges","oranges","bananas",
   "bananas","oranges","bananas"];
    alert(A.most()) // [oranges,4]

    A.push("bananas");
    alert(A.most()) // [bananas,oranges,4]
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it this way for finding the most common integer

```
function mostCommon(arr) {
    // finds the first most common integer, doesn't account for 2 equally common integers (a tie)

    freq = [];

    // set all frequency counts to 0
    for(i = 0; i < arr[arr.length-1]; i++) {
      freq[i] = 0;
    }

    // use index in freq to represent the number, and the value at the index represent the frequency count 
    for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      freq[arr[i]]++; 
    }

    // find biggest number's index, that's the most frequent integer
    mostCommon = freq[0];
    for(i = 0; i < freq.length; i++) {
      if(freq[i] > mostCommon) {
        mostCommon = i;
      }
    }

    return mostCommon;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution.

```
var max_frequent_elements = function(arr){
var a = [], b = [], prev;
arr.sort();
for ( var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++ ) {
    if ( arr[i] !== prev ) {
        a.push(arr[i]);
        b.push(1);
    } else {
        b[b.length-1]++;
    }
    prev = arr[i];
}


var max = b[0]
for(var p=1;p<b.length;p++){
       if(b[p]>max)max=b[p]
 }

var indices = []
for(var q=0;q<a.length;q++){
   if(b[q]==max){indices.push(a[q])}
}
return indices;
```

};

Answer (score 0):

All the solutions above are iterative.

Here's a ES6 functional mutation-less version:

```
Array.prototype.mostRepresented = function() {
  const indexedElements = this.reduce((result, element) => {
    return result.map(el => {
      return {
        value: el.value,
        count: el.count + (el.value === element ? 1 : 0),
      };
    }).concat(result.some(el => el.value === element) ? [] : {value: element, count: 1});
  }, []);
  return (indexedElements.slice(1).reduce(
    (result, indexedElement) => (indexedElement.count > result.count ? indexedElement : result),
    indexedElements[0]) || {}).value;
};
```

It could be optimized in specific situations where performance is the bottleneck, but it has a great advantage of working with **any** kind of array elements.

The last line could be replaced with:

```
  return (indexedElements.maxBy(el => el.count) || {}).value;
```

With:

```
Array.prototype.maxBy = function(fn) {
  return this.slice(1).reduce((result, element) => (fn(element) > fn(result) ? element : result), this[0]);
};
```

for clarity

Answer (score 0):

Why should someone be interested in the most frequently occurring item rather than the second most or perhaps the first n most occurring items, or maybe the last n appearing ones?

```
import {TrueSet} from "@ut8pia/classifier/queue/TrueSet.js";
import assert from "assert";

const 
    data = ['1','2','2','3','4'],
    expected = '2';
```

In your question, I see two implicit questions:

- What is the simplest way to calculate the number of occurrences of each item?

A `TrueSet` can automatically calculate the number of occurrences of each stored item and retrieve them through the method `n(item)`. All you need to do is add your data to a `TrueSet`.

```
const
    set = new TrueSet()
        .letAll(data)
```

- How can items be sorted based on these occurrences?

Another instance of a `TrueSet` can sort the items according with the number of occurrences maintained by the first instance.

```
const
    repr = item => set.n(item),
    sorting = new TrueSet(repr)
        .letAll(set)
```

That's all!

The most appearing item can easily be retrieved as last item `peek(false)` in the `sorting`.

```
const
    got = sorting.peek(false);

assert.equal(got, expected)
```

The concept of `TrueSet` is introduced by the [@ut8pia/classifier](https://github.com/ut8pia/classifier) library.

Answer (score 0):

My dime (using `Array.reduce/-.map/-.filter`):

```js
console.log(findMaxFrequencies(['1','2','2','3','4','2','3','3','4']));
  
function findMaxFrequencies(arr) {
  const freqs = arr.reduce( (acc, v) => ({...acc, [v]: (acc[v] ?? 0) + 1}), {} );
  const maxFreq = Math.max( ...Object.values(freqs) );
  return Object.entries(freqs)
    .filter(([val, freq]) => freq === maxFreq).map( v => 
      `value: ${v.join(`, frequency: `)}`);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If the array contains strings try this solution

```
    function GetMaxFrequency (array) {
    var store = array;
    var frequency = [];  // array of frequency.
    var result;   // holds the max frequency element.

    for(var v in store) {
        var target = store[v];
        var numOccurences = $.grep(store, function (elem) {
        return elem === target;
        }).length;
        frequency.push(numOccurences);

    }
    maxValue = Math.max.apply(this, frequency);
    result = store[$.inArray(maxValue,frequency)];
    return result;
}
var store = ['ff','cc','cc','ff','ff','ff','ff','ff','ff','yahya','yahya','cc','yahya'];
alert(GetMaxFrequency(store));
```

Answer (score -1):

A fairly short solution.

```js
function mostCommon(list) {
  var keyCounts = {};
  var topCount = 0;
  var topKey = {};
  list.forEach(function(item, val) {
    keyCounts[item] = keyCounts[item] + 1 || 1;
    if (keyCounts[item] > topCount) {
      topKey = item;
      topCount = keyCounts[item];
    }
  });

  return topKey;
}

document.write(mostCommon(['AA', 'AA', 'AB', 'AC']))
```

Answer (score -1):

This solution returns an array of the most appearing numbers in an array, in case multiple numbers appear at the "max" times.

```
    function mode(numbers) {
      var counterObj = {}; 
      var max = 0;
      var result = [];
      for(let num in numbers) {
        counterObj[numbers[num]] = (counterObj[numbers[num]] || 0) + 1; 
        if(counterObj[numbers[num]] >= max) { 
          max = counterObj[numbers[num]];
        }
      }
      for (let num in counterObj) {
        if(counterObj[num] == max) {
          result.push(parseInt(num));
        }
      }
      return result;
    }
```