# Get the highest value in div container

Tags: jquery, html, survey, highest

I'm very new to this, just trying to piece together snippets from other posts. I have a survey scale which you rate from 1 - 5. After that it will display your answer for each item. [image: Survey results sample]

I would like to get the majority of votes.

Sample in my screenshot is 5. Then I will display an equivalent result let's say 1 will display Factor A message and so on ... then 5 will display the message in Factor E. I am having a hard time doing it.

Can you give me an idea?

Here's the code for the output:

```
<div class="col-sm-3" id="scoreDiv">
<p>#1 - <span class="score" id="score1"></span></p>
<p>#2 - <span class="score" id="score2"> </span></p>
<p>#3 - <span class="score" id="score3"> </span></p>
<p>#4 - <span class="score" id="score4"> </span></p>
<p>#5 - <span class="score" id="score5"> </span></p></div>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Comment: I actually don't know where to start? First I tried to set a class for highest score but still no luck. This is actually different from what I wanted to do.        http://jsfiddle.net/gsak6jfe/4/

Comment: I am a beginner in jquery I can read and understand but I don't have an idea how to start to do it.

Comment: Well throw your result values in an array then do something like this to get the value with the highest frequency: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3783950/get-the-item-that-appears-the-most-times-in-an-array

Comment: but difference is it depends on what the user select in survey. I can't declare a definite number like var score = [1,2,2]. The value is display in <span class="score">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
 var _array = [];
 $("#scoreDiv p").each(function(index, el) {
 var text = $(this).text().split(" ");
    text = text[0].split("#");
   _array.push(text[1]);
 });
   alert(Math.max.apply(Math,_array));
```

Comment: I tried and I only get the total value of the ratings.

Comment: This is related to this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52196826/how-to-get-the-frequent-value-output-inside-the-div/52196917?noredirect=1#comment91343511_52196917