# How to get the frequent value output inside the div?

Tags: jquery, arrays

Saw this article [How can i get most repeated value from Array in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25304109/how-can-i-get-most-repeated-value-from-array-in-javascript)

I am a newbie in jquery, I would like to know if how can I get the array values if it is declared inside an **id** or **class** div?

```
<p>#1 - Rate: <span class="score" id="score1"> 5</span></p>
<p>#2 - Rate: <span class="score" id="score2"> 5</span></p>
<p>#3 - Rate: <span class="score" id="score3"> 5</span></p>
<p>#4 - Rate: <span class="score" id="score4"> 5</span></p>
<p>#5 - Rate: <span class="score" id="score5"> 5</span></p>
```

This is the output looks like:

```
<div id="totalScore">55555</div>
```

I did this by getting the rates of 5 items

```
jQuery("#totalScore").append(jQuery(".list1").text());
```

In the article above the value is inside an array

```js
var arr = [{
  values: "Number of pips"
}, {
  values: 4
}, {
  values: 4
}, {
  values: 4
}, {
  values: 5
}, {
  values: 2
}, {
  values: 6
}, {
  values: 6
}, {
  values: 5
}];



var uniqs = {};

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  uniqs[arr[i].values] = (uniqs[arr[i].values] || 0) + 1;
}

var max = {
  val: arr[0],
  count: 1
};
for (var u in uniqs) {
  if (max.count < uniqs[u]) {
    max = {
      val: u,
      count: uniqs[u]
    };
  }
}

alert(max.val);
```

How to convert it like this? By getting only the value in **id="totalScore"** or **.list1**?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can i get most repeated value from Array in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25304109/how-can-i-get-most-repeated-value-from-array-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate over each `.score` with `each`, incrementing the associated value in an object. Then, iterate over the object's `entries`, identify the one with the maximum value, and get its key (by accessing the `[0]` index of the entry):

```js
const counts = {};
$('.score').each((_, span) => {
  const num = span.textContent.trim();
  counts[num] = (counts[num] || 0) + 1;
});
console.log(
  Object.entries(counts).reduce((a, item) => (
    item[1] > a[1]
    ? item
    : a
  ), [,0])[0]
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>#1 - Rate: <span class="score" id="score1"> 5</span></p>
<p>#2 - Rate: <span class="score" id="score2"> 5</span></p>
<p>#3 - Rate: <span class="score" id="score3"> 3</span></p>
<p>#4 - Rate: <span class="score" id="score4"> 4</span></p>
<p>#5 - Rate: <span class="score" id="score5"> 5</span></p>
<p>#6 - Rate: <span class="score" id="score6"> 4</span></p>
```

Comment: Thank you very much sir! But how can I say append this or display it in a div? Let say The output will display in <div id="mostFrequentNumber">5</div>. Appreciate sir!

Comment: Just select that div and set its `text`?

Comment: Did it but instead it displays Not availableNot availableNot availableNot availableNot available. Though it appears in my console. Appology sir I know I sound stupid but I am a beginner in this. Appreciate it. Thanks

Comment: I don't know how that would happen, just replace the `console.log` with `$('#mostFrequentNumber').text` ?

Comment: Nope it doesn't identified the value. But thank you very much for your help!